# Originality requirements for Bloggers

Tags: discussion, blog

What is the standard for original content; can we re-purpose our own, older content from elsewhere (i.e. personal blogs)? Also, are we permitted to re-post after the content goes up on Stack Exchange?

In participating shortly at BlogCritics, their terms were that you were allowed to re-post your content only *after* it had been posted to the BC site. They also disallowed re-posting one's own content.

What is the Stack Exchange blog model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick note that all Blog Overflow content also falls under our [CC-by-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/) license, like user contributions on the rest of the network. You can see the full TOS on [our legal page](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

That means if you want to repost something that has already been published to Blog Overflow, you need to attribute it and link back to the Blog Overflow page (and, in your example, attribute the author as yourself).

I would say if you're just going to repost an article you've already posted on your own personal blog, it's probably not a good blog post. If it already exists in blog form elsewhere on the internet, copying it to a Blog Overflow domain doesn't help make the Internet a better place. If you're going to update the information, improve formatting, or otherwise improve the article, I don't see a problem with that, provided it is in line with our TOS and licensing.

Comment: I have occasionally relied on q/a's from stack to inform posts of mine and just wanted to verify that if I repurpose articles (e.g. to construct a narrative regarding food writing and the usefulness of stack) that it wouldn't be considered some violation. I only mean this question to assume parity between licenses (cc by-sa <> cc by-sa)

Comment: The CC-BY-SA license is if someone other than the author wants to repost it. The author doesn't need a copyright license—he/she is the copyright holder. So the attribution requirements don't apply, legally speaking. (Though the SE TOS is written weirdly in that section, and honestly I'm not sure whoever wrote it has actually read the CC-BY-SA license—it violates CC-BY-SA 4(a) for example)